# modelstate.isvalid false because the item always null

Tags: asp.net

so I tried making an asp.net core 2 (visual studio 2017) . Tried to make a simple view, new, edit, delete for master bank. I have succeeded on the view and create new, but now I'm stuck on the edit part. So, when the user click edit, I open new window and show the detail for them to edit, and then when they click save button, then I saved the values (like when create new). it's just that simple. but for some reason, the modelstate.isvalid for edit always false, and when I tried debugging I found that the items all returned null (they all showed on the view), except for the primary key. pls help where I did wrong :

the class :

```
        public class MsBank
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
            [RegularExpression(@"\b[A-Z0-9]{1,}\b", ErrorMessage = "Must Be Uppercase")]
            public string BankCode { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
            public string BankName { get; set; }

            public string BankBranch { get; set; }

            private SqlConnection con;
            private void connection()
            {
                PrjCommon dbhandle = new PrjCommon();
                con = new SqlConnection(dbhandle.GetSetting());
            }

    public bool AddBank(List smodel)
    {
        connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveMsBank", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (var item in smodel) { 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankCode", item.BankCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankName", item.BankName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BankBranch", item.BankBranch);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdatedBy", "Me");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdatedFromModule", "NET");
        }
        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (i >= 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
    }
```

the view :

```
     @model List[MsBank]
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    
        
            

            @foreach (var item in Model) {
            
                Code :
                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.BankCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.BankCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            
            
                Name :
                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.BankName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.BankName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            
            
                Branch :
                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.BankBranch, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.BankBranch, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            
            
                
            
            }
        
    
    }
    @ViewBag.Message
    
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    

    @section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    }
```

and the controller :

```
       public ActionResult Edit(string BankCode)
        {
            MsBank ms = new MsBank();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(ms.GetData(BankCode));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(string BankCode,List smodel)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (smodel.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MsBank ms = new MsBank();
                        if (ms.AddBank(smodel))
                        {
                            ViewBag.Message = "Bank Edited Successfully";
                            ModelState.Clear();
                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else { ViewBag.Message = "Empty Record"; }
                }
                return View(smodel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = e.ToString();
                return View(smodel);
            }
        }
```

so, to make it more clear, modelstate.isvalid above returned false (when debug I found that) because bankname is invalid because it's null, and so bankbranch is null too

Comment: see if this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040956/modelstate-isvalid-false-because-the-item-always-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to me that your view is taking in an IEnumerable of msbank `@model IEnumerable [WBMS.Models.MsBank]` when it should really just be taking in a single instance of it. You are then iterating through the model, which is changing the name of form fields on your edit view from `BankCode` to `item_BankCode` which is why you are returning null on those values.

Try changing your edit view to this:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.MsBank

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @:Code:
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
    @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankCode, "", new
    {
          @class = "text-danger"
    })

    @:Name:
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankName, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
    @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankName, "", new
    {
        @class = "text-danger"
    })

    @:Branch:
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankBranch, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
    @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankBranch, "", new
    {
        @class = "text-danger"
    })

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

@ViewBag.Message

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

Comment: thx for the answer. u point me to the right direction. I was wrong that I make a List but then I use IEnumerable on the view, and then I use class as parameter on the controller.

pls see the 1st post again, I have edited it to the changes that I make so all use List
but now for the edit after httppost, have returned model.isvalid true, but the smodel returned no record.

where did I do wrong ?

Comment: Just to clarify, your `ms.GetData(BankCode)` method retrieves a list of `MsBank`?

Comment: after trying again, now I fully understood what u meant. so I shouldnt use for each but instead use other means

so I change foreach with :
       @for (var i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)

and change item.BankCode with Model[i].BankCode (and for bankname and bankbranch too of course)

and all good

thx for the help

Comment: now.. is there anything I need to do to accept ur answer ? or just let it be like this and case closed ?
sorry.. still newbie here on stackoverflow

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Cick on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. This link has directions on how to accept an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: funny how I didnt see that check mark at all before.. well, I have changed it to green (that's all it need to accept ur answer right ?).
so, once again.thx for the fast answer. really appreciate it.

Comment: That's all you need. No problem at all :)